# How to transform Minutes in Hours and Minutes using Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

My professor gave us an homework to next Monday. We or I have to write a code using pointers where the user will insert (Integer Minutes) and my code will convert these minutes in hours and minutes...

For example, user inserts: 333
My code will return: 5 hours and 55 minutes by doing 333 / 60 = 5,55...

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

    int ConverTemp(int *minutes, int *hours)
    {
        *hours = *minutes / 60;
        *minutes = *minutes / 10;

        if(*minutes > 60)
        {
          *minutes = *minutes - 60;
          *hours = *hours + 1;
        }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

        int minutes = 0;
        int hours = 0;


          printf("Insert Minutes: ");
          scanf("%i", &minutes);

          ConverTemp(&minutes,  &hours);

          printf("Hours: %i ",     hours);
          printf("Minutes: %i ", minutes);

        return 0;
    }
```

A friend of mine said I'm not using pointers in my code but references. I thought I had understand my concept but as he said I didn't.

Comment: There are no *references* in C. You are in fact using pointers in `ConvertTemp` function. Wheher this is what your professor expected, I can't tell. But your approach looks reasonable to me.

Comment: there's no reference in C, it's a C++ concept

Comment: 333/60=5.55 but that is not 5 hours and 55 minutes.  You still need to do .55*60 to get the minutes. In short, 333 minutes is 5 hours and 33 minutes.  Need to have your math right before writing code.

Comment: @LelreFerreira: It's still wrong.  This one was right by coincidence.  Try 555 minutes.  It should give 9 hours and 15 minutes.  Your code gives 9 hours and 55 minutes.

Comment: That was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

change function `ConverTemp` to

```
void ConverTemp(int *minutes, int *hours)
{
    *hours = *minutes / 60;
    *minutes = *minutes %60;
}
```

return type should be change to void as its not returning anything and calling the function bu reference.

the minutes would be the remainder of minutes when divided by 60

NOTE: its c++ code

Answer (score 0):

You program does use pointers, and dereferences them to access the values.

First, assigning zeros is not needed:

```
    int minutes = 0;
    int hours = 0;
```

those zeros are never used.

Second, your time arithmetic looks sort of dubious. 333 minutes is 5 hours and 55 minutes, really?? 5 hours 33 minutes seems a more exact result:

```
int ConverTemp(int *minutes, int *hours)
{
    *hours = *minutes / 60;
    *minutes %= 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*hours = *minutes / 60;       // (remove)
*minutes = *minutes / 10;     // (remove)

while(*minutes > 59)   // (modify)if statement becomes while and 60 to 59 
    {
      *minutes = *minutes - 60;
      *hours = *hours + 1;
    }
```

I see a small issue with the initial if statement you put and I will tell you how to fix it, but first go in your program and put in 180 minutes... it will return 3 hours and 18 minutes which is wrong, you do not need some of the unnecessary code.. to get this to work you need to remove the above lines and make the if statement a while statement, take note that the "> 60" in the while loop is now "> 59" because you are looking for the number more than 60 and above not 61 and above. If the professor have not yet covered while loops for you, it is simple and easy, the while loop is just like an if statement, how ever it will keeps looping until the number of minutes is not more than 60 !